# How to listen to probe requests from android devices

Tags: android, request, android-wifi, wifi

There is a way to listening to 802.11 probe requests that sent by a client? I want to develop some android application that can do it over rooted devices (or unrooted, if it's possible), using the internal WIFI or through an external usb WIFI.
A 802.11 probe request is a special frame sent by a client station requesting information from either a specific access point, specified by SSID, or all access points in the area, specified with the broadcast SSID.

Comment: Note: OP is referring to 802.11 probe requests.